# Master slides disappear even if they are pinned in PowerPoint. Any idea what could be wrong?

Tags: master

Made a new PowerPoint for use with PC and Mac. 29 masters are pinned and it's saved as a template, and we've created 106 slides to choose from based on the masters.

When a user tries to create a new PowerPoint and deletes all the slides (not the masters), it deletes all but 5 of the masters so you can't add them back in the presentation.

Other threads say it seems the link between the masters has been lost so I started over and recreated the PowerPoint by copying the design and pasting in new masters making sure they were pinned then tested numerous times on PC and Mac.

If you delete one or two slides at a time, you can add them back in using masters with no issue, but the problem of disappearing masters persists if you delete all the pages at once.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: This are all words, but no information that can help. Without us having your template and understanding better which manipulations you're doing, there's not much that we can do.